# XmlDocument.LoadFromUriAsync blocks on no internet connection in Metro-ui Style App

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, xmldocument

I am using this code to get an xml from an uri

```
        try
        {
            doc = await XmlDocument.LoadFromUriAsync(new Uri(apiRequest));
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
```

The problem is that the function isn't throwing any exception when not connected to the internet, and the whole program just blocks. It does throw an exception if I set the uri to something invalid like "http://notanactualluri.com" or to a valid uri that doesn't contain an xml.